# Spring Data JPA Page Query Wrong Result

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a query for paging operation. But when I give the sort column, the answer is wrong. All Completed fields come true. Completed fields in database not true. If there is no sort column, the result is correct. The same problem persists when you do not give sort in Pageable and add an order to the query.

> It works when i remove ***todoitem0_.item_desc as item_des4_0_*** from the
> query. But I couldn't understand the problem

> Problem is fixed when the description field is defined as
> varchar(255). But I need to define ***@Lob***

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api/item")
public class TodoItemController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    private TodoItemDto getUserItems(Authentication authentication,
            @RequestParam("page") int page, @RequestParam("sizePerPage") int sizePerPage){

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page,sizePerPage, Sort.by("createdAt").descending());
        return todoItemService.getUserItems(((CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getId(),pageable);

    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TodoItemServiceImpl implements TodoItemService {
    @Override
    public TodoItemDto getUserItems(long userId, Pageable pageable){
        
        Page<TodoItem> itemPage = todoItemRepository.findUserItems(userId, pageable);
        TodoItemDto dto = new TodoItemDto();
        dto.setContent(itemPage.getContent());
        dto.setTotal((int)itemPage.getTotalElements());
        return dto;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface TodoItemRepository extends JpaRepository<TodoItem, Integer> {
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT i FROM TodoItem i "
            + "INNER JOIN Todo t ON t.user.id = ?1 "
            + "WHERE i.todo.id = t.id ")
    Page<TodoItem> findUserItems(long userId, Pageable pageable);
    
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class TodoItem{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Item name not be blank")
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String itemName;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Item description not be blank")
    @Lob
    private String itemDesc;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "todoId")
    private Todo todo;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean completed = false;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable=false, updatable = false)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd / MM / yyyy")
    private Date createdAt;
    
    @PrePersist
    protected void onCrearedAt() {
        this.createdAt = new Date();
    }
}
```

**Hibernate Sql Query**

```
select
    todoitem0_.id as id1_0_,
    todoitem0_.completed as complete2_0_,
    todoitem0_.created_at as created_3_0_,
    todoitem0_.item_desc as item_des4_0_,
    todoitem0_.item_name as item_nam5_0_,
    todoitem0_.todo_id as todo_id6_0_ 
from
    items todoitem0_ 
inner join
    todo todo1_ 
        on (
            todo1_.user_id=?
        ) 
where
    todoitem0_.todo_id=todo1_.id 
order by
    todoitem0_.created_at desc limit ?
```

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I tried this. But the problem continues

Comment: Not null comes true(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice this '1' digit in your query,

```
+ "INNER JOIN Todo t ON t.user.id = ?1 "
```

This is messing with your resultset

Comment: I tried this way ==>  "INNER JOIN Todo t ON t.user.id = :userid ". But the problem continues

Comment: and if you leave this qyestion sign and just remove the '1'?